# Origin and context of adjunctions inducing equivalences between full subcategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, galois-theory, order-theory, duality

The following is well-known.

**Theorem.** *Let $F\dashv U$ be a pair of adjoint functors
$$F\colon \mathcal C\to \mathcal D, \qquad U\colon \mathcal D\to\mathcal C$$
with unit $(\eta_A\colon A\to U(F(A)))_{A\in\mathcal C}$ und counit $(\varepsilon_B\colon F(U(B)) \to B)_{B\in\mathcal D}$. Then $F$ and $G$ restrict to equivalences $\mathcal C'\to\mathcal D'$ and $\mathcal D'\to\mathcal C'$ between the full subcategories $\mathcal C'$ and $\mathcal D'$ given by
$$\mathcal C':=\{A\in\mathcal C\mid \eta_A\text{ is an isomorphism}\}$$
and
$$\mathcal D':=\{B\in\mathcal D\mid \varepsilon_B\text{ is an isomorphism}\}.$$*

Posets can be considered as categories. This yields:

**Corollary.** *Let $P$ and $Q$ be posets, and $f\colon P\to Q$ and $u\colon Q\to P$ monotone maps with
$$\forall a\in P.\, \forall b\in Q.\,a\leq u(b)\iff f(a)\leq b.$$
Then $f$ and $u$ restrict to isomorphisms between the induced sub-posets $P'$ and $Q'$ given by
$$P':=\{a \in P\mid a = u(f(a))\}$$
and
$$Q':=\{b\in Q\mid f(u(b))=b\}.$$*

**Questions.**

1. Can someone give me the original references for the theorem and the corollary above? Of course, in some sense, the corollary must be hidden in the works of Galois (or in the works of people who cleaned up his theory), since taking $P$ to be $(\mathcal P(F), \subseteq)$ for any field $F$, $Q$ to be $(\mathcal P(G), \supseteq)$ for any group $G$ of automorphisms of $F$, and considering
   $$f\colon \mathcal P(F) \to \mathcal P(G),\, a\mapsto\{g\in G\mid \forall x\in a. \, g(x)=x\}$$
   and
   $$u\colon \mathcal P(G) \to \mathcal P(F), \, b\mapsto \{x\in F\mid \forall g\in b. \, g(x)=x\}$$
   yields the fundamental theorem of Galois theory up to a concrete characterization of $P'$ and $Q'$. But I'm interested in who extracted the "abstract content" of this proof in the sense of the corollary and who, after that, formulated the generalization to categories in the sense of the theorem.
2. Not just the relation "$g(x)=x$" between field elements $x$ in $F$ and automorphisms $g$ in $G$ yields a pair of functions $f\colon \mathcal P(F) \to \mathcal P(G)$ and $u\colon \mathcal P(G) \to \mathcal P(F)$ satisfying the conditions of the corollary, but in fact *any* relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ yields such a pair of functions $f\colon \mathcal P(A) \to \mathcal P(B)$ and $u\colon \mathcal P(B) \to \mathcal P(A)$. (Such a pair functions constituting an adjunction between posets is called a *Galois connection*, by the way.) Thus relations are a powerful tool to generate Galois connections. *Is there an analogue of relations that allows one to generate pairs of adjoint functors between categories?*
3. Not just the fundamental theorem of Galois theory can be formulated as an instance of the above theorem, but also the Gelfand–Naimark theorem, the Stone duality, the duality between affine schemes and commutative rings, and the Pontrjagin duality are corollaries of the above theorem up to concrete characterization of $\mathcal C'$ and $\mathcal D'$. I guess most of them are recast as applications of the above theorem only with hindsight. But can the above theorem be also used as a *guide* that helps and inspires proving completely new equivalences?

Comment: Not sure about 1. For 2, lookup "profunctor". For 3, have you computed any examples? 4 seems too vague to answer.

Comment: Googling "profunctor" I haven't found a text that explains how profunctors induce adjunctions in the same way that relations induce Galois connections. Concerning 3: I haven't computed any examples. My hope is that the answer to this question is well-known among category theorists. Concerning 4: I agree that it is a soft question. But it would be helpful if an expert could just tell me "I used the theorem to prove an equivalence result I wouldn't have discovered without the theorem" or "In my experience nearly all equivalence results arise without the theorem".

Comment: That's remarkable: I just looked into Mac Lane's CWM for reference of the above theorem but it seems it isn't in there!

Comment: The "Theorem" is an obvious corollary of the triangle equations, which are certainly in CWM.  A random adjunction will restrict to quite a small, probably empty, equivalence. The situations where there is an interesting one are probably obvious from the outset. So I am not sure that there is any interesting "Theorem" that CWM omitted. Expressing it all in modern abstract language gets the whole question upside down from a historical perspective.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thanks. But I don't agree that just because a statement has an easy or even trivial proof it is a poor theorem. (Your comment somehow suggests this viewpoint.)

Comment: OK, as a useful exercise for a new grad student, run through the adjunctions that you know and characterise their equivalent subcategories.  My guess is that those where the two categories are "approximately the same idea", eg topological spaces and locales, will have big equivalent subcategories, but other situations will yield empty ones.

Comment: The case of posets is in CWM IV-5, Exercise 2. Part of the exercise is the question of a generalization to arbitrary adjunctions. So the author was aware of the theorem but assumed that it is more fun for the reader to work it out independently.

Comment: Maybe work of Kan? He did discover adjunctions, after all.

Comment: @MarcOlschok Indeed, thanks!

Comment: @PaulTaylor I see, thanks. However, given the adjunction between topological spaces and locales and the goal to restrict this adjunction to an equivalence between full subcategories, how do you get the idea to consider *sober* spaces and *spatial* locales "by hand", i.e., without knowing the above theorem. Isn't the whole task much easier when one knows that it's useful to consider the objects for which the unit/counit is an isomorphism?

Comment: In a previous version of my post I asked whether the theorem above can be formulated as an equivalence between the category of algebras over the monad induced by the adjunction and the category of coalgebras over the comonad induced by the adjunction (this was motivated by the fact that this holds for adjunctions between posets, in which case the algebras and coalgebras turn out to be the same as the fixed points $P'$ and $Q'$). (1/2)

Comment: Thanks to MO's "Related"-feature I realized that this question has already been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36766/adjunctions-algebras-of-the-induced-monad-vs-coalgebras-of-the-induced-comonad?rq=1 (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1

I don't know if they are the *first* publications, but two very early references are

1. Garrett Birkhoff (1940). *Lattice Theory*.
2. Øystein Ore (1944). "[Galois Connexions](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1944-055-00/S0002-9947-1944-0010555-7/S0002-9947-1944-0010555-7.pdf)". (see Theorem 2 for a formulation of the "Corollary")

Remarks in these texts indicate that Galois connections between power set lattices $\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathcal P(Y)$ induced by relations $R\subseteq X\times Y$ are due to Birkhoff, while Ore introduced the theory of Galois connections between arbitrary posets. From 2:

> It has already been pointed out by Garrett Birkhoff that any binary
> relation defines a correspondence of the type of a Galois connexion between
> the subsets of two sets

In the 1948 revised edition of 1, Birkhoff remarks in a footnote that the "Corollary" in the special case of Galois connections induced by relations is due to himself, while he refers to 2 as the origin of a particular axiomatization of Galois connections between arbitrary posets that he gives in the text.

As remarked by Marc Olschok in the comments, the "Theorem" occurs implicitly in

3. Saunders Mac Lane. *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.

in the form of an exercise (Exercise 2, §IV-5). I don't have the first edition of that book to check whether this exercise already appears in the first edition. Given the similarity between adjunctions (due to Kan) and Galois connections, the generalization from the "Corollary" to the "Theorem" may well be a "folklore result", if not due to Mac Lane.

Comment: I have checked the first edition of Mac Lane and the exercise does appear in exactly the same place. However, I never noticed this exercise, and first learnt of the result in Proposition 4.2 of Part 0 of Lambek and Scott's *Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic*. There's no attribution, so it does seem to be considered a folk result (probably due to the simplicity of the proof).

Comment: Thanks, interesting!